# Parametrs isEqualToString Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I write program 
NSString *key;
if key is different paramsURL and uri show 
inscription

try write this code

```
if (![key isEualToString:@"paramsURL"] && ![key isEualToString:@"uri"]){

    NSLog(@"I'm happy ");

}
```

I don't sure is correct please help me

Comment: Try to write your question more clearly.

Comment: What's your real code? Because I don't know the method `isEualToString:`. `isEqualToString:`, yes, but not yours. And what's wrong with your code?

Comment: What is your question? What are you tryign to achieve / what is not working ? Do you have an error? What is it ? What results are you expecting?